# Tensorflow Serve SignatureDefs for classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, serve

I trained a BERT text classifier following these steps, with own texts and some modifications:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert

To export the model and run it with Tensorflow Serve works well:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker

Unfortunately, I can not really figure out how to define the SignatureDefs for a classifier, so that the classifier endpoint for Tensorflow Serve is defined. The `:predict` endpoint works well and seems to be the default signature.

Obviously, I have to define the signatures, when I save the model. Since the documentation is not very exhaustive on this topic, I am not sure how to define the classifier signature.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/signature_defs

In the above example for BERT, the `serving_results` just define the `reloaded_model` with `tf.constant(examples)` and instantiates it with `serving_results = tf.sigmoid(serving_results['classifier')]`.

So, I assume I have to give the activation function and the `classifier` signature as arguments, when calling the `model.save` method.

`predict`endpoint works, `classify` endpoint gives the error:

`{"error": "No classification inputs found in SignatureDef: inputs {\n  key: \"text\"\n  value {\n    name: \"serving_default_text:0\"\n    dtype: DT_STRING\n    tensor_shape {\n      dim {\n        size: -1\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\noutputs {\n  key: \"classifier\"\n  value {\n    name: \"StatefulPartitionedCall_2:0\"\n    dtype: DT_FLOAT\n    tensor_shape {\n      dim {\n        size: -1\n      }\n      dim {\n        size: 1\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nmethod_name: \"tensorflow/serving/predict\"\n"}`

I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right documentation for defining the Signatures can be found here.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_basic?hl=en

```
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        'predict_images':
            prediction_signature,
        tf.compat.v1.saved_model.signature_constants
            .DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            classification_signature,
    },
```